# Como salvar um HABTM depois do save no controller?

Tags: cakephp, habtm

Tenho uma tabela on `Users` HABTM `Solicitations`.
Depois de salver minha solicitação, eu quero incluir um novo dado na tabela `solicitations_users`

```
if($this->request->is('post')) {

$this->Solicitation->save($this->request->data);

// Aqui é meu codigo onde pego a ID do usuário, 6 por exemplo
// Agora eu quero salvar a User ID na "Solicitation" que acabei de criar.

// O codigo abaixo nao funciona

 $data = array($this->data['User']['id'] => 6);
 $this->Solicitation->save($data);
```

Como salvar uma novo `user_id` na tabela `associations_users` depois do `$this->save()` associado a `solicitation`que acabei de criar?? 
Vlw

Comment: primeira pergunta é "o uqe você deseja salvar?"

Comment: editei minha pergunta. Vlw

Comment: você poderia explicar o contexto pelo qual você tem fazer um update no registro que acabou de criar? Não seria mais simples passar o Id no registro que foi incluído? O que acontece quando você executa seu código? dá algum erro ou não salva registro nenhum?

Answer (score 1):

Par salvar `associations_users` basta usar

```
if($solicitationId = $this->Solicitation->save($this->request->data)){
    $data = array(
        "user_id" => $this->data['User']['id'],
        "solicitation_id" => $solicitationId
    );
    $this->AssociationsUser->save($data);
}
```

Imagino que seja o que você precisa.

Todo método `save` retorna o `id` do último registro que foi salvo, sendo assim você pode pegar este dado e utilizar em outro `save` ou `update`